# unique elements in python list

Tags: string, python-3.x, arraylist, substring

I have a list

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'ab','d','bc','b','c','d']

result = ['a','b','c','d'] (desired output)

result = ['a','b','c','d','ab','bc' ] (my output using set())
```

How can I compare substring also to get the unique list

Comment: Why is `d` not in your desired output?

Comment: mistake - added ````d````

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want the set of all characters in your list `a` (though this doesn't match your desired output). If this is the case, then use:

```
set(''.join(a))
```

This joins your list into one long string, then splits it into a list of characters, then apply set To get:

```
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

To transform back to list:

```
>>> list(set(''.join(a)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: `list(set(''.join(a)))` the second `list` call is redundant.

Comment: I would like to compare substring. if 'b' in 'bc', I don't want that element

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sacul you could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do this

```
list(set([letter for entry in a for letter in entry]))
```

which will work for strings or list of lists.